# Why is freezing and optimizing tf graph causing slower inference

Tags: optimization, graph, tensorflow, freeze

I have a segmentation model based on VGG. I have frozen the graph, optimized the graph, and quantized the graph to eight bits. None of them running the inference faster than the original .ckpt model.

The command I use to freeze the graph is:

```
`~/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph --input_graph=model_.pb --input_binary=true --input_checkpoint=./model.ckpt --output_graph=out.pb --output_node_names=adam_logit`
```

The command I used to optimize the graph was:

```
~/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/optimize_for_inference \
--input=frozen.pb \
--output=optimized.pb \
--frozen_graph=True \
--input_names=image_input \
--output_names=adam_logit
```

The command I use to quantize the graph is:

```
~/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph \
--in_graph=optimized.pb \
--out_graph=eightbit.pb \
--inputs=image_input \
--outputs=adam_logit \
--transforms='
add_default_attributes
remove_nodes(op=Identity, op=CheckNumerics)
fold_constants(ignore_errors=true)
fold_batch_norms
fold_old_batch_norms
fuse_resize_and_conv
quantize_weights
quantize_nodes
strip_unused_nodes
sort_by_execution_order'
```

I load the pb files in python as follows:

```
sess, ops = gu.load_graph('frozen.pb')
g = sess.graph
print("operations ", len(ops))
print("graph names: \n", [n.name for n in g.as_graph_def().node])
input_layer = g.get_tensor_by_name('image_input:0')
keep_prob = g.get_tensor_by_name('keep_prob:0')
logits = g.get_tensor_by_name('adam_logit:0')
helper.save_inference_samples(runs_dir, data_dir, sess, image_shape, logits, keep_prob, input_layer)
```

To run an inference on an image using the ckpt version of the model takes:
.6 seconds
using the frozen.pb model takes: 3.5 seconds
using the optimized.pb model takes 2.6 seconds
using the quantized eightbit model takes 7.5 seconds

Also, when using the frozen.pb and optimized.pb models I get a resource allocation error after running the inference on about 20 images. I do not have this issue with the ckpt and eightbit.pb models.

How can I make my pb models do the inference faster?